# Login Form issues PHP/MySQL.

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having a pig of a time with my code. I am new to this and am struggling greatly.

I have several issues, firstly one problem is that I am trying to use a login form which is connected to an SQL database, but do not get an error when incorrect data or no data is entered, but it looks to log in.

Secondly, I am trying to show the username on each page when users are logged in, which works, but only for those users that have been manually entered into the database. Any user that has been added via my registration form, do not show, though they are showing in phpmyadmin.

My **login page** code for the first problem is:

```
<?php


echo '<h3>Sign in</h3>';

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
    {
        /*the form hasn't been posted yet, display it
          note that the action="" will cause the form to post to the same page it is on */
        echo '<form method="post" action="">
            Username: <input type="text" name="Username" />
            Password: <input type="password" name="Password" />
            <input type="submit" value="Sign in" />
         </form>';
    }
    else

        {
            //the form has been posted without errors, so save it
            //notice the use of mysql_real_escape_string, keep everything safe!


        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Username']);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Password']);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = '$username' AND Password = '$password'";             
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if(!$result)
            {
                //something went wrong, display the error
                echo 'Something went wrong while signing in. Please try again later.';
                header("location:index.php");
                //echo mysql_error(); //debugging purposes, uncomment when needed
            }
            else
            {
                {                
                    {
                    //set the $_SESSION['signed_in'] variable to TRUE
                    $_SESSION['signed_in'] = true;

                    //we also put the user_id and user_name values in the $_SESSION, so we can use it at various pages
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                    {
                        $_SESSION['UserID']    = $row['UserID'];
                        $_SESSION['Username']  = $row['Username'];
                    }

                    echo 'Welcome, ' . $_SESSION['Username'] . ' <a href="index2.php">Proceed to the forum Home page</a>.';
                    }
                }
            }   
        }

?>
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: First things first, use `PDO` instead of `mysql_`

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they have been removed from PHP 7, your code will stop working when you upgrade to that version. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Comment: Also note that you are open for SQL injections.

Comment: you have no connection string.  +1 for @GeraldSchneider as the following link is also deprecated  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `mysql_query()` returns `FALSE` when there is an actual mysql error. That can be syntax error, invalid constraint insert or input datatype mismatch. If any inserted username and password combination can potentially be valid, that means there won't be any errors.

In your case, if **username** or **password** are wrong, it means that 0 rows (no data) is returned which is **not** an **error**. So in your code, variable `$result` is never `FALSE`, and that is why your code never goes in error loop.

In order to fix this, you will need to change your code to check if number  of returned rows is greater than 0 rather than checking if result is `TRUE`. You can achieve this by using `mysql_num_rows()` function.
Changed code should look like this

```
$result = mysql_query($sql); 
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($num_rows < 0){
   //put some code for error
}
```

**Further notes :** 
 If you don't want to use PDO you can use mysqli instead of mysql. Also you are vulnerable to sql injection. It would be really good if you take a look at [prepared statements](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) and how to make data coming to your server more secure.

Comment: Thanks @Bozic that really helped. I don't suppose you have any advice on my second issue (see above) with regards to user details only showing on my pages for users that have been manually entered into phpadmin but not for usersadded via my registration form. Thanks